# Where is the best place in angularfire to call Off?

Tags: angularfire

I use in my controller something like this (For every added message I increment my game and then remove this message):

```
    $scope.items = $firebase(messRef);
    $scope.items.$on("child_added", function(value) {
            var snapshot = value.snapshot;
            var name = snapshot.name, data = snapshot.value;

            //I need to increment some global value
           game.addPeople(data.people);
           //then I need to remove this value 
           $scope.items.$remove(name);  
    });
```

When I switch view and go back to this view. The listener is called twice for one added value (I understand why but...). Where is the best place to call $scope.items.$off('child_added'); ?

Or is another way how to prevent this behaviour?

Thanks for reply

Comment: What is the real use case here? There's probably much better ways to go about this, such as not using child_added at all. There's really no "best place" to call $off(), you can do it from anywhere that you have access to the original function you attached. Where you do that also depends on the use case.

Comment: @Kato I added my real use case. Is there better way how to do that? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit unclear why child_added is necessary here. It's possible that you may just want to directly use $scope.items in your view/ng-repeat code and skip this.

Assuming the use case is solid, the best option here is probably to move all of this to a service which is not lost/reinstated each time the controller loads.

If it needs to be handled in the controller, then listening for a $destroy event should work.

```
function handleAdd(value) {
        var snapshot = value.snapshot;
        var name = snapshot.name, data = snapshot.value;

        //I need to increment some global value
       game.addPeople(data.people);
       //then I need to remove this value 
       $scope.items.$remove(name);  
}

$scope.items = $firebase(messRef);
$scope.items.$on("child_added", handleAdd);

// remove listener when controller is unloaded
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
    $scope.items.$off('child_added', handleAdd);
    // or if $scope.items will no longer be used...
    // $scope.items.$off();
});
```